# Recursive Assignment Using Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm stuck working on an assignment problem using recursion. I am stuck on how to set up the recursion using Python. I have a list of values and two people to do an equitable distribution (as equitable as possible). If the difference in assets between the two people is equal, the asset should be assigned to the first person. Please take a look and make suggestions on what I am doing wrong with the set up of the recursion:

```
def Asset_Allocation(person1, person2, allocation, numLoops):
    '''Recursive Function to Assign Assets to People''' 
    #Value[0] or Value[1:]
    numLoops += 1
    print "Number of Loops:", numLoops
    num_items = len(Value) - len(allocation)
    d = person1 - person2
    if num_items == 0:
        return person1, person2, allocation
    elif d == 0 and numLoops < len(Value):
        allocation.append('Chuck')
        person1 = person1 + Value[numLoops - 1]
        Asset_Allocation(person1, person2, allocation, numLoops) 
    else:           
        m = (d + Asset_Allocation(person1, person2, Value[1:], numLoops))
        a = (d - Asset_Allocation(person1, person2, Value[1:], numLoops))
        if m < a:
            allocation.append('Chuck')
            person2 = person2 + Value[numLoops - 1]
        else: 
            allocation.append('Allison')            
            person1 = person1 + Value[numLoops -1]


    return person1, person2, allocation

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

#Create Tuples of Values    
Value = (2, 1, 3)

#Variables to Assign People
Chuck = 0
Allison = 0
Allocation = []

#Global Variable to track number of Recursive Calls
NumLoops = 0

# Call Asset Allocation Function to Solve the Problem
Chuck, Allison, Allocations = Asset_Allocation(Chuck, Allison, Allocation, NumLoops)

#Print Results
print 'Allocations:'
print Asset[0], Value[0], Allocations[0]
print Asset[1], Value[1], Allocations[1]
print Asset[2], Value[2], Allocation
print 'Allison Total', Allison
print Allocation
```

Comment: A couple of comments explaining what you expect `d`, `m` and `a` to be would be helpful... `d = difference`?

Comment: D is Difference. I needed to use m and a to keep track of the asset allocation. If d >= 0 then I needed to use a max of (d + Asset Value, d - Asset Value) if the d < 0 I needed to assign based on min of (d + Asset Value, d - Asset Value)

Comment: In your else case, you have a scalar `d` +/- the return value of a call to `Asset_Allocation`. `Asset_Allocation` returns a tuple of values. This behavior should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question, especially the part where you say "*If the difference in assets between the two people is equal, the asset should be assigned to the first person*".

So my understanding is that you want to distribute something as equitably as possible between 2 people, with the first person getting any exceeding value. I'd like to present a solution that works for this:

```
def assets_allocation(alloc):

    def sub(alloc, lst1, tot1, lst2, tot2, results, diff):
        if alloc: # there's more to allocate
            head, tail = alloc[0], alloc[1:] # split between head and tail
            # recurse, first giving the value of head to person 1, then to person 2
            results, diff = sub(tail, lst1+[head], tot1+head, lst2, tot2, results, diff)
            results, diff = sub(tail, lst1, tot1, lst2+[head], tot2+head, results, diff)
        else:
            newdiff = tot1 - tot2
            if results and newdiff == diff: # same value as previous results, add
                return results+[(lst1, lst2)], newdiff
            elif not results or 0 <= newdiff < diff: # new value
                return [(lst1, lst2)], newdiff
        return results, diff

    results, diff = sub(alloc, [], 0, [], 0, [], None)
    return results
```

Testing:

```
>>> assets_allocation((2, 1, 3)) # two results here
[([2, 1], [3]), 
 ([3], [2, 1])]

>>> assets_allocation((2, 1, 4)) # just 1 result
[([4], 
  [2, 1])]
```